# google-map-react: Adding circle radius

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I want to add a red circle radius around my `center`. I am using this package https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react and here is my code:

```
<GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{key: this.googleAPIKey}}
      defaultCenter={{lat: this.props.latitude, lng: this.props.longitude}}
      defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
      yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
      onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) =>
        new google.maps.Circle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          map,
          center: {lat: this.props.latitude, lng: this.props.longitude},
          radius: 275,
        })}
        >
      <AnyReactComponent
        lat={this.props.latitude}
        lng={this.props.longitude}
      />
    </GoogleMapReact>
```

However, i get the following error:

[image]

I followed the instructions in the docs and tried googling how to solve this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Try not setting yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals to true? Just keep yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals on that line without the ={true}

Answer (score 4):

Just do :

```
 onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) =>
        new maps.Circle({
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this error occurs since Google Maps API *could not be loaded/or it is getting loaded **after** the `onGoogleApiLoaded` function is invoked*, that's the reason why this error occurs. It is unclear though to say *why* Google Maps API is failed to load since not enough details has been provided in the question.

According to [`google_map.js`](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/45ecda13e6a91a20ca683aca89bce30eaf4c8bf5/src/google_map.js#L795) some addition details about error should be displayed in the console which could reveal why it happens:

```
.catch(function (e) {
    // notify callback of load failure
    _this._onGoogleApiLoaded({ map: null, maps: null });
    console.error(e); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    throw e;
 });
```

But the example looks *correct* and this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dzzpji) demonstrates how to draw a circle.